# Number of $n$-tuples such that $x_i+1\neq x_{i+1}$

Tags: combinatorics

I need to find number of $10$-tuples $(x_1,x_1,\dots,x_{10})$ with elements from the set $\{0,1,2,\dots 9\}$ such that $x_{i}+1\neq x_{i+1}$.

My part of solution:

If element is not equal to $9$ then we have $9$ elements which can be after this one. But if the element is $9$, we have $10$ choices. Let us first count number of solutions if $0$ can't be after $9$. For the first element we have $10$ choices, and for every element after that $9$ choices, all together
$$10\cdot9^9$$
possible tuples.

Now, I would like to add all tuples where sequence $9,0$ occurs at least once, but I have problem how to count this? If there is one occurrence, we have to choose $1$ place for it among $9$ possible and we have $9^8$ choices for other elements (again we don't allow $9,0$ for other elements), i.e.
$$9\cdot 9^8.$$
Now it gets complicated when I count for $2$ occurrences since when I place $9,0$ and there is space of length $1$ between them, I have only $8$ choices for that space. Also, when space length is $2$ then the first space have $9$ choices, but the second has either $9$ or $8$ depending weather the first space was $7$ and we only have to eliminate $7,8,9$ or we have something else, like $5$, so we must eliminate both $5,6,9$ and $5,8,9$.

I think this will get me to the right result, but it is very complicated and I was wondering if there is some more simple solution?

Comment: Idk if that's a lot easier but you could count all the bad tuples (those for which $x_i+1=x_{i+1}$ for some i)

Comment: I implemented a Python program to calculate the number of valid 5-tuples, and calculated the number of valid combinations of two 5-tuples. Although I am still looking for a way to calculate it in a straightforward way, the number of valid 10-tuples equals 4,275,561,136.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using an inductive argument to derive the number of valid tuples for $n+1$:

[image]

This sequence confirms Markus Scheuer's answer.

Comment: In column $n=3$, the numbers should be $91,81,82,82,82,...$, and in the next column, $828, 737, 747, 746, 746,...$

Comment: In a Python shell, you can type `a=[1]*10` and then repeatedly enter `s=sum(a);a=[s]+[s-i for i in a[:-1]];print(a)`. After nine iterations, the result of `sum(a)` should agree with Scheuer.

Comment: This is sommething I understant better that the previous answer, but I don't know why they differ?

Comment: In my first answer, the numbers were the same for end digits $..1$, $..2$ to $..9$. This was wrong. Example: there are a total of $91$ admissible sequences with two digits. You may append $0$ to any of them. You may append $1$ to $81 = 91 - 10$ of them, but $2..9$ to $82 = 91 - 9$ of them.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is based upon the *[Goulden-Jackson Cluster Method](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806036)* which is a convenient technique to derive a *[generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)* for problems of this kind.

> We consider words of length $10$ built from an alphabet $$\mathcal{V}=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$$ and the set $B=\{01,12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89\}$ of *bad words*, which are not allowed to be part of the words we are looking for. We derive a generating function $f(s)$ with the coefficient of $s^{10}$ being  the number of searched words of length $10$.

According to the paper (p.7) the generating function $f(s)$  is
\begin{align*}
f(s)=\frac{1}{1-ds-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}
\end{align*}
with $d=|\mathcal{V}|=10$, the size of the alphabet and $\mathcal{C}$ the *weight-numerator* of bad words with
\begin{align*}
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})=\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[01])+\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[12])+\cdots+\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[89])
\end{align*}

> We calculate according to the paper
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[01])&=-s^2\\
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[12])&=-s^2-s\cdot\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[01])\\
> &=-s^2+s^3\\
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[23])&=-s^2-s\cdot\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[12])\\
> &=-s^2-s(-s^2+s^3)\\
> &=-s^2+s^3-s^4\\
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[34])&=-s^2+s^3-s^4+s^5\\
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[45])&=-s^2+s^3-s^4+s^5-s^6\\
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[56])&=-s^2+s^3-s^4+s^5-s^6+s^7\\
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[67])&=-s^2+s^3-s^4+s^5-s^6+s^7-s^8\\
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[78])&=-s^2+s^3-s^4+s^5-s^6+s^7-s^8+s^9\\
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[89])&=-s^2+s^3-s^4+s^5-s^6+s^7-s^8+s^9-s^{10}\\
> \end{align*}

We observe the polynomials in $s$ reflect the more and more consecutive overlaps $\{n-1,n\}\cap\{n,n+1\}$ which occur when going from $[01]$ up to $[89]$. In fact this is a consequence of the inclusion-exclusion principle.

> We obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> f(s)&=\frac{1}{1-ds-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-10s-\sum_{j=0}^8\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[j,j+1])}\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-10s+9s^2-8s^3+7s^4-6s^5+5s^6-4s^7+3s^8-2s^9+s^{10}}\tag{1}\\
> &=1+10s+91s^2+828s^3+7534s^4+68552s^5+623756s^6\\
> &\qquad+5675568s^7+51642104s^8+469892512s^9+\color{blue}{4275561136}s^{10}\\
> &\qquad+38902414208s^{11}+\cdots
> \end{align*}

The last line was calculated with the help of Wolfram Alpha.

> We conclude the number of wanted words of length $10$ is according to (1)
>   \begin{align*}
> [s^{10}]f(s)=\color{blue}{4275561136}
> \end{align*}

We take a look at a small example.

> **Example: $n=3$**
>
> The coefficient of $s^3$ gives according to (1): $[s^3]f(s)=828$. This implies there are $1000-828=172$ bad words.
>
> These bad words are listed below organised in columns with $20$ rows 
>   \begin{array}{cccccccc}
> 001&120&231&342&453&564&675&786&897\\
> 010&121&232&343&454&565&676&787&898\\
> 011&122&233&344&455&566&677&788&899\\
> 012&123&234&345&456&567&678&789&901\\
> 013&124&235&346&457&568&679&801&912\\
> 014&125&236&347&458&569&689&812&923\\
> 015&126&237&348&459&578&701&823&934\\
> 016&127&238&349&467&589&712&834&945\\
> 017&128&239&356&478&601&723&845&956\\
> 018&129&245&367&489&612&734&856&967\\
> 019&134&256&378&501&623&745&867&978\\
> 023&145&267&389&512&634&756&878&989\\
> 034&156&278&401&523&645&767&889&\\
> 045&167&289&412&534&656&778&890&\\
> 056&178&301&423&545&667&780&891&\\
> 067&189&312&434&556&670&781&892&\\
> 078&201&323&445&560&671&782&893&\\
> 089&212&334&450&561&672&783&894&\\
> 101&223&340&451&562&673&784&895&\\
> 112&230&341&452&563&674&785&896&
> \end{array}